# Non-Proprietary Virtual Image Clients?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, virtual-pc

Just to ask if there are any non-proprietary virtual image clients available, i.e. an application capable of running .vhd and/or .vmdk based virtual images?   I have searched online, but have not been able to find any.

Note, I am actually looking to avoid using the bloated VMware Server 2.0, with its web interface and resource hungry service to run my VMware virtual images - if anyone has any ideas on this, I would appreciate it.  Before anyone suggests it, I have tried several times in the past to convert .vmdk images to .vhd files, without success.  This is **not** a possible solution for me.

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**VirtualBox**](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a superb (and totally free) virtual machine that I have used in the past for running all sorts of setups (both Windows and Linux). It is capable of directly using VMDK and VHD images, as well as its own format.

Now, I'm not sure precisely what you mean by proprietary, but if you simply mean paid software, then VirtualBox should clearly be fine for you. If you want something open source, then I recommend [**VirtualBox OSE**](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions), which only lacks a few advanced features (see the details on the page). It's licensed under the GPL, so I *believe* this means that it is non-proprietary, though someone may need to clarify this...

Comment: Noldorin, Thank you for your answer. +1. By non-proprietary, I mean that you are not tied to one specific format. Both Virtual PC and VMware Server are free, but you are forced to choose between one or the other.

Comment: @MagicAndi: Ah, fair enough. VirtualBox has support for VMware/VirtualPC images as well, however - is this not enough?

Comment: Yes, it definitely looks to answer my question.  The fact that it is open source, and allows me to re-use my existing library of .vhd and .vmdk suggests that VirtualBox is the answer to my virtualization woes.  Thanks, Noldorin!

Comment: @MagicAndi: Glad you have your solution. :)